# Function Name and Pointer to function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, embedded

Did the name of the function represent an pointer to this function like array?

If I declare an function as follow `void fu (void);` and an array of pointer to  function like that `void(*ptr_fn[8])(void);` so can I do that `ptr_fn[0] = fu;`

Comment: That's correct, it should work as you describe it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It is also equivalent to:

```
ptr_fn[0] = &fu ;
```

i.e. the `&` is optional.

Equally when calling the function through the pointer

```
ptr_fn[0]() ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*ptr_fn[0])() ;
```

The use of the `&` and `*` operators serves to emphasise perhaps that you are dealing with a function-pointer, and so aids maintenance and comprehension by humans, but has no effect on the compiler's code generation.

Answer (score 3):

No, and the name of an array does not represent a pointer, either.

The name represents the function, but there's an implicit conversion when you use the function name in an expression.

See 4.3 Function-to-pointer conversion:

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function.